# How to map index settings, tokenizer, analyzer NEST V2

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have tried mapping a tokenizer and an analyser to my index using the fluent API, but it does not appear. The field mappings work.

```c#
 var filters = new string[] { "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "stop",
                        "ngram" };


            client.CreateIndex("defaultindexname", index => index

                 .Settings(f => f
                     .Analysis(analysis => analysis
                         .Tokenizers(tokenizers => tokenizers
                                 .EdgeNGram("ngram", t => t
                                 .MinGram(2)
                                 .MaxGram(15)
                             )
                         )
                         .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
                                 .Custom("auto-complete", a => a
                                 .Filters("lowercase")
                                 .CharFilters(filters)
                                 .Tokenizer("standard")
                             )
                         )

                     )
                 )
                 .Mappings(m => m
                    .Map<Type>(l => l
                     .Dynamic(DynamicMapping.Ignore)
                     .Properties(p => p
                            .String(s => s
                                .Name(n => n.Name)
                                .Boost(5)
                            )
                            .String(s => s
                                .Name(n => n.Address)
                            )
                            .Number(s => s
                                .Name(n => n.Id)
                            )
                            .Completion(c => c
                                .Name(n => n.Suggest)
                                .Payloads()
                            )
                            .Nested<NestedType>(o => o
                                .Dynamic(DynamicMapping.Ignore)
                                .Name(n => n.Branches)
                                .Properties(ilfbp => ilfbp
                                    .Number(s => s
                                        .Name(n => n.Id)
                                    )
                                    .String(s => s
                                        .Name(n => n.Name)
                                    )
                                    .String(s => s
                                        .Name(n => n.Address)
                                    )

                                )
                            )
                        )
                     )
             ));
```

I have successfully creates the tokenizer and the analyser in Sense with putting JSON.

```json
PUT /defaultindexname/_settings
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram": {
               "type": "ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 10
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "ngram"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I add the tokenizer and the analyzer using the fluent api?

Comment: After quick test, looks like your mapping works correctly. May you check if `client.CreateIndex(..).IsValid` is `true`?

Comment: `client.CreateIndex(..).IsValid` is `false`. If I comment out the `.Settings(..)` then it is valid.

Comment: In your fluent mapping you are passing filters to `CharFilters`, but in your elasticsearch request you are passing them to filter. Which one is correct?

Comment: Passing the `filters` array into `.Filters(..)` instead of `.CharFilters(..)` has solved it.

I have removed `.CharFilters(..)` now.

Thanks!